# Angular: Can't call component I created

Tags: angular

I created a new component,But I can not read it in the app.

In my main component file: app.component.html
I have:

```
<h1>First App</h1>
<app-red-light></app-red-light>
```

In my second component file: red-light.component.html

I have:

```
<p>red-light works!</p>
```

**Which I call red-light
In main components so it does not appear to me**

My App.Module:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RedLightComponent } from './red-light/red-light.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RedLightComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Did you add `RedLightComponent` to your `AppModule`? Do you get any errors in your console?

Comment: It should automatically be added there as soon as I create components

Comment: And I do see it there

Comment: I added all my code in the app.module

Comment: @JorgeDask in that case please share the code (or minimal code that demonstrates the issue) on Stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you re-builded your application once more? Changes involving the modules(for instance creating new components) require running the application by `ng serve` again

Comment: My Bad, I did not connect to localhost: 4200